# Architecture question involving search & session state

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I have a grid with several thousand rows that can be filtered and sorted. On each row you can click a details button, which will bring you a new page with detailed information about the page. Because this is a button, you can't middle click or right click and open in a new tab. In addition, when clicking back you lose your filters and search results.

To solve this problem, I considered the following: Switch the buttons to links, and when filtering and searching, use get instead of post requests. This way, you could switch to new pages with a right click or middle click, and if you did follow a link normally, back would work properly.

This change was not made however. We were asked add a 'next result / previous result' set of buttons on the details page, that would allow you to navigate. While not an elegant solution, it would at least work.

I proposed adding querystring parameters to the details page, that would regenerate the search query based on filter, and allow you to get the next and previous results in code.

A team member took issue with this solution. He believes that it is a waste of server resources to re-query the database. Instead, a solution was proposed to add session variable that included a list of results. You could then use that to navigate.

I took issue with that because you can't have multiple tabs open without breaking navigation, and new results aren't appended to the list in real time. Also, if you worried about optimization, session would be the last thing to use since it eats memory and prevents server replication... unless you store the results back in the database.

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session doesn't sound like a winner, won't scale with lots of users.

Hitting the database repeatedly does seem unnecessary, but it depends on the cost - how many users, how often would they refresh/filter and what is the cost of that query?

If you do use querystrings you could cache the pages by parameter.

What about some AJAX code on that button to retrieve details - leave the underlying grid in place and display details in a div/panel or a new window/tab.